# Android Printing API on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, printing, tablet, galaxy

I would like to add wireless printing to my android 2.2 application which is targeted for the Galaxy tablet.  I see that the internet browser has a print option so I am assuming that an activity hook must exist, and I was hoping that someone has figured this out.  I have found a possibility using the PrinterShare application from Mobile Dynamix, but my preference would be to no require a 3rd party.

Here is the code example that they provide, just for reference.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("com.dynamixsoftware.printershare");
i.setDataAndType(data_uri, data_type);
startActivity(i);
```

Where:

data_uri - Uri of the object to print, such as "file:///sdcard/something.pdf" or "content://something"

data_type - Mime type. The following mime types are supported:
"application/pdf"
"text/html"
"text/plain"
"image/png"
"image/jpeg"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Printing is not yet supported on Android. You have to use a 3rd party solution like Mobile Dynamix, [HP iPrint for Android](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/smart-phones-handhelds-calculators/mobile-apps/app_details.html?app=tcm:245-799203&platform=tcm:245-799126&jumpid=ex_r11400_go/iprintphotoforandroid) or [Send2Printer](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/send-2-printer_jzk.html).

Intents are described here:

http://www.openintents.org/en/node/735

http://www.openintents.org/en/node/278

Comment: There is an API now in 4.4 KitKat finally :) developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Printing

Answer (score 0):

> Use build in **PrintManager Service**

```
private void doWebViewPrint() {
        mWebView = new WebView(PrintActivity.this);
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(urlToPrint);
    }

    protected void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
        mPrintJob = printManager.print(docName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    }
```

you need to set

```
urlToPrint = "whatUrlToPrint"
docName = "anyDocumentName";
```