# Postscript driver for Android?

Tags: android, printing, driver, postscript, printer-control-language

I am looking to program an Android app which is simply a print driver that converts a file to postscript and/or PCL and then sends it to a network printer.  My first concern is printing pdf files.  Do any of you know of a Java (or I guess I could use C/C++ and JNI) library for converting pdf to PS/PCL?  The key issue here is that I can't use any of the built-in Java print libraries, since those aren't included on Android.

I don't have any ambition to sell the app, or distribute it under my name, or anything of that nature, so if you can point me to some open-source converters which I can use directly, that would be great.

Comment: You could begin by splitting it into logically separate subtasks - I'm pretty sure you'll get more useful answers to "how do I convert to PS" and "how do I upload to FTP" than to a combination of both.

Comment: Android does not have "print drivers" without substantial firmware modifications. Your desired feature ("convert a file to postscript") is not a "driver". A "'universal' postscript converter" is impossible, no different than a "'universal' MP3 converter" could turn a photo into an MP3 file.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  The app would consist of a service, which would be available to other applications, and then an application front-end, in which the user can choose a file to print, choose the network address of the printer, etc.  This question is concerned with _what_ to send to the printer and not _how_ to send it.  @CommonsWare: So, I'll need to write (or find) a converter for each file type I want to support?

Comment: "So, I'll need to write (or find) a converter for each file type I want to support?" -- yes. That's how it works in the rest of the world. You will notice that there is no "universal postscript thingamabob" for Windows, Linux, or OS X, either. On a desktop-style OS, apps like Word or Impress speak to a print driver API, for which there may be a Postscript implementation on a given machine...but only Word knows how to print Word files, and only Impress knows how to print Impress files. Conversion to Postscript directly is not significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

The "send to a network printer" part of this question is a duplicate of existing Stack Overflow questions, [*Printing API in Android*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160661/printing-api-in-android) and [*Android Printing API on Galaxy Tab*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580088/android-printing-api-on-galaxy-tab).

The answer, thanks to Horcrux7 in August 2011:

Currently there are some bad working third party apps. Nothing is a professional solution.... All which need a printing API in Android should vote for it.

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1148
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13275