# Printing capabilities in android

Tags: android

I have made research on printing capabilities in android and came to the solution that there is no official sdk available and printing via Bluetooth is not possible.

There is a third party api provided by send2printer app.when i supposed to run the project i got the "Beta Expired" message.

non official iprint sdk seems to be paid one.

Then how we make the printing capability in android? please guide me on this..

Thanks.

Comment: Android direct USB printing using OTG cable is available through a small library.
see link http://myhowtohelp.blogspot.in/2014/01/library-to-print-from-android-device-usb.html

Answer (score 0):

The following links can provide you some help

i> [Android Printing API on Galaxy Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580088/android-printing-api-on-galaxy-tab)

ii> [Printing API in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160661/printing-api-in-android)